# Adding a video element with Popcorn TTML subtitles

Tags: javascript, html, video, popcornjs, ttml

I have a page where I want to insert a video element with a TTML subtitle using PopcornJS as you can see in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RK6fa/). All is working fine except the subtitles. They don't show. When I do something like `<video src="myvideo.mp4" data-timeline-sources="data.ttml" />` the subtitles work correctly.

So am I doing something wrong here or is it just not possible with PopcornJS to insert a `video` element, set the `data-timeline-sources` attribute and play the video with that subtitle file?

My data.ttml subtitle file looks like this:

```
<tt xmlns:tts="http://www.w3.org/2006/04/ttaf1#styling" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2006/04/ttaf1">
<body region="subtitleArea">
  <div>
    <p xml:id="subtitle1" begin="0.50s" end="2.5s">
      Test subtitle 1
    </p>
    <p xml:id="subtitle2" begin="3.0s" end="5.0s">
      Test subtitle 2
    </p>
    <p xml:id="subtitle3" begin="5.5s" end="8.5s" >
      Test subtitle 3a<br/>
      Test subtitle 3b
    </p>
    <p xml:id="subtitle4" begin="9.5s" end="12.0s">
      Test subtitle 4
    </p>
    <p xml:id="subtitle5" begin="13.0s" end="15.0s">
      Test subtitle 5
    </p>
  </div>    
</body>
</tt>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Popcorn TTML parser](http://popcornjs.org/code/parsers/parserTTML/popcorn.parserTTML.js) is a script, so put it in a script tag as in the following demos:

- [Popcorn 1.0 TTML parser Plug-in Demo](http://popcornjs.org/code/parsers/parserTTML/popcorn.parserTTML.html)
- [Popcorn TTML parser documentation](http://popcornjs.org/popcorn-docs/parsers/#TTML%20parser)

IE10 is the only browser that supports TTML natively. Chrome supports [WebVTT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/WebVTT). Firefox supports neither. Here are some tutorials about each:

- [Create WebVTT or TTML files with Caption Maker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg123962)
- [WebVTT Primer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/WebVTT)
- [Intro to WebVTT and track](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-introduction-to-webvtt-and-track/)